# How to optimize the query like this

Tags: mysql, sql

My current query looks like this :

```
SELECT a.id,b.size,c.item_no,d.size_id 
FROM inv a LEFT JOIN product b ON a.id=b.id 
LEFT JOIN all_products c ON a.id=c.id and a.size=c.size 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT qty, code, code2,status FROM prod_stock where status='1')    
  AS d ON c.web_code=d.code 
LEFT JOIN prod_size e ON a.size_id=e.prod_size_id 
WHERE a.id='123456' ORDER BY a.id,e.prod_size_id;;
```

As table grows( all_products has over 70,000 items), the above query takes 2~7sec.
Any suggestion? My current setting is LAMP..

Comment: Please post the primary keys and foreign keys your database model has. This query is pretty simple and should be fast... unless you forgot to add a foreign key.

Comment: Indexing a column also helps you!

Comment: My problem is this system is old. tables listed above use MyISAM and there are some index and primary key but no foreign key. all_products(MyISAM ) usually has 70,000 and product(InnoDB) table has about 30,000 and prod_stock(MyISAM ) has about 70,000 items. the problem getting worse when inv(MyISAM ) table has over 1,000 items with the same id like '123456'

Comment: Well, it sounds like you already have an idea on how to improve this. Don't use MyISAM and add some indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by removing the subquery and the last `JOIN` (it does not seem necessary):

```
SELECT i.id, p.size, ap.item_no, ps.size_id 
FROM inv i LEFT JOIN
     product p
     ON i.id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     all_products ap
     ON i.id = ap.id and i.size = ap.size LEFT JOIN 
     prod_stock ps
     ON ap.web_code = ps.code AND status = 1 
WHERE i.id = 123456
ORDER BY i.id, i.size_id;
```

I removed the quotes on the constants.  Presumably, they are actually numbers (if they are strings, then add the constants back in).

You want indexes on all the `JOIN` keys.  For the first table, you specifically want `inv(id, size, size_id)`.

Comment: Thank you. It was easier than I thought.